# Java class as a Monitor

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

i need to write a java program but i need some advice before starting on my own.

**The program i will be writing is to do the following:**

- Simulate a shop takes advanced order for donuts
- The shop would not take further orders, once 5000 donuts have been ordered

Ok i am kind of stuck thinking if i should be writing the java-class to act as a Monitor or should i use Java-Semaphore class instead?

Please advice me. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any java object can work as a monitor via the wait/notify methods inherited from `Object`:

```
Object monitor = new Object();

// thread 1    
synchronized(monitor) {
    monitor.wait();
}

// thread 2
synchronized(monitor) {
    monitor.notify();
}
```

Just make sure to hold the lock on the monitor object when calling these methods (don't worry about the `wait`, the lock is released automatically to allow other threads to acquire it). This way, you have a convenient mechanism for signalling among threads.

It seems to me like you are implementing a bounded producer-consumer queue. In this case:

1. The producer will keep putting items in a shared queue.
2. If the queue size reaches 5000, it will call `wait` on a shared monitor and go to sleep.
3. When it puts an item, it will call `notify` on the monitor to wake up the consumer if it's waiting.
4. The consumer will keep taking items from the queue.
5. When it takes an item, it will call `notify` on the monitor to wake up the producer.
6. If the queue size reaches 0 the consumer calls `wait` and goes to sleep.

For an even more simplified approach, have a loop at the various implementation of [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html), which provides the above features out of the box!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Ok how about writing with Java-CyclicBarrier class is it a better option for this?

Comment: @JasonMayhem: Not really, the `CyclicBarrier` construct seems more fit for the master-worker pattern (i.e. team of threads that do some work, then wait for each other to finish), rather than producer-consumer. For this scenarion, you can use an implementation of `BlockingQueue` instead.

Comment: Thank you Tudor. I guess from the BlockingQueue link, that this can be done easily with just writing classes to act as Producer and Consumer. So i can skip the monitor implementation right?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the core of this exercise is updating a counter (number of orders taken), in a thread-safe and atomic fashion.  If implemented incorrectly, your shop could end up taking more than 5000 pre-orders due to missed updates and possibly different threads seeing stale values of the counter.

The simplest way to update a counter atomically is to use `synchronized` methods to get and increment it:

```
class DonutShop {

    private int ordersTaken = 0;

    public synchronized int getOrdersTaken() {
        return ordersTaken;
    }

    public synchronized void increaseOrdersBy(int n) {
        ordersTaken += n;
    }

    // Other methods here
}
```

The [synchronized methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) mean that only one thread can be calling either method at any time (and they also provide a memory barrier to ensure that different threads see the same value rather than locally cached ones which may be outdated).  This ensures a consistent view of the counter across all threads in your application.

(Note that I didn't have a "set" method but an "increment" method.  The problem with "set" is that if client has to call `shop.set(shop.get() + 1);`, another thread could have incremented the value between the calls to `get` and `set`, so this update would be lost.  By making the whole increment operation atomic - because it's in the synchronized block - this situation cannot occur.

---

In practice I would probably use an [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) instead, which is basically a wrapper around an `int` to allow for atomic queries and updates, just like the `DonutShop` class above.  It also has the advantage that it's more efficient in terms of minimising exclusive blocking, and it's part of the standard library so will be more immediately familiar to other developers than a class you've written yourself.

In terms of correctness, either will suffice.

Comment: Thank you for the help Andrzej. Much appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Like Tudor wrote, you can use any object as monitor for general purpose locking and synchronization.

However, if you got the requirement that only x orders (x=5000 for your case) can be processed at any one time, you could use the `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore` class. It is made specifically for use cases where you can only have fixed number of jobs running - it is called *permits* in the terminology of `Semaphore`

If you do the processing immediately, you can go with

```
private Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(5000);

public void process(Order order)
{
    if (semaphore.tryAcquire())
    {
        try
        {
            //do your processing here
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.release();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException("can't take more orders");
    }
}
```

If if takes more than that (human input required, starting another thread/process, etc.), you need to add callback for when the processing is over, like:

```
private Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(5000);

public void process(Order order)
{
    if (semaphore.tryAcquire())
    {
        //start a new job to process order
    }
    else
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException("can't take more orders");
    }
}

//call this from the job you started, once it is finished
public void processingFinished(Order order)
{
    semaphore.release();
    //any other post-processing for that order
}
```